# SharePoint 2013 Foundation with iOS (SharePoint and OneNote app)

Tags: apple-ios, onenote

Is there anything known about an incompatibility or problems accessing SharePoint Foundation 2013 from iOS?

Are there any known settings on SharePoint for iOS access?

In my setup, I have 2013 Foundation on W2012 server behind an apache reverse proxy. So far everything works: Login via web interface, accessing files from office applications and OneNote 2013.

However, with **iOS** there are only troubles:

1. With the Sharepoint app, I can successfully login but Links tab shows *Something went wrong: The operation couldn't be completed. (Alamofire.AFError error 3.)*. The "Recent" in Sites tab just shows "Loading" forever
2. From within OneOnte app (which is far more important), I can open the notebooks but no sections are displayed. It also fails to sync. Sometimes the following error is shown: "We ran into a problem syncing your notebook. (Error code: 0x803D000A)"

From the logs, it can be seen that the requests fail with 401 (Forbidden):

```
[25/Nov/2017:20:01:56 +0100] "HEAD /OneNote/Testbook/ HTTP/1.1" 401 2973 "-" "Microsoft Office OneNote/16.6/171005 (iOS/11.1.1; Phone; en-US; AppStore; Apple/iPhone10,1)"
[25/Nov/2017:20:01:56 +0100] "HEAD /OneNote/Testbook/ HTTP/1.1" 401 572 "-" "Microsoft Office OneNote/16.6/171005 (iOS/11.1.1; Phone; en-US; AppStore; Apple/iPhone10,1)"
[25/Nov/2017:20:01:56 +0100] "HEAD /OneNote/Testbook/ HTTP/1.1" 302 695 "-" "Microsoft Office OneNote/16.6/171005 (iOS/11.1.1; Phone; en-US; AppStore; Apple/iPhone10,1)"
[25/Nov/2017:20:01:57 +0100] "HEAD /OneNote/Testbook/ HTTP/1.1" 401 137 "-" "Microsoft Office OneNote/16.6/171005 (iOS/11.1.1; Phone; en-US; AppStore; Apple/iPhone10,1)"
[25/Nov/2017:20:01:57 +0100] "HEAD /OneNote/Testbook/ HTTP/1.1" 302 696 "-" "Microsoft Office OneNote/16.6/171005 (iOS/11.1.1; Phone; en-US; AppStore; Apple/iPhone10,1)"
[25/Nov/2017:20:01:58 +0100] "HEAD /OneNote/Testbook/ HTTP/1.1" 401 137 "-" "Microsoft Office OneNote/16.6/171005 (iOS/11.1.1; Phone; en-US; AppStore; Apple/iPhone10,1)"
[25/Nov/2017:20:01:58 +0100] "HEAD /OneNote/Testbook/ HTTP/1.1" 302 696 "-" "Microsoft Office OneNote/16.6/171005 (iOS/11.1.1; Phone; en-US; AppStore; Apple/iPhone10,1)"
[25/Nov/2017:20:01:58 +0100] "HEAD /OneNote/Testbook/ HTTP/1.1" 401 137 "-" "Microsoft Office OneNote/16.6/171005 (iOS/11.1.1; Phone; en-US; AppStore; Apple/iPhone10,1)"
[25/Nov/2017:20:01:59 +0100] "HEAD /OneNote/Testbook/ HTTP/1.1" 302 696 "-" "Microsoft Office OneNote/16.6/171005 (iOS/11.1.1; Phone; en-US; AppStore; Apple/iPhone10,1)"
[25/Nov/2017:20:01:59 +0100] "HEAD /OneNote/Testbook/ HTTP/1.1" 401 137 "-" "Microsoft Office OneNote/16.6/171005 (iOS/11.1.1; Phone; en-US; AppStore; Apple/iPhone10,1)"
[25/Nov/2017:20:01:59 +0100] "HEAD /OneNote/Testbook/ HTTP/1.1" 302 696 "-" "Microsoft Office OneNote/16.6/171005 (iOS/11.1.1; Phone; en-US; AppStore; Apple/iPhone10,1)"
[25/Nov/2017:20:02:00 +0100] "POST /OneNote/Testbook/_vti_bin/webs.asmx HTTP/1.1" 500 1230 "-" "OneNote/16006000.17100500 CFNetwork/889.9 Darwin/17.2.0"
[25/Nov/2017:20:02:00 +0100] "POST /OneNote/Testbook/_vti_bin/webs.asmx HTTP/1.1" 500 1230 "-" "OneNote/16006000.17100500 CFNetwork/889.9 Darwin/17.2.0"
[25/Nov/2017:20:02:01 +0100] "POST /OneNote/Testbook/_vti_bin/webs.asmx HTTP/1.1" 401 754 "-" "OneNote/16006000.17100500 CFNetwork/889.9 Darwin/17.2.0"
[25/Nov/2017:20:02:01 +0100] "HEAD /OneNote/Testbook/ HTTP/1.1" 302 137 "-" "Microsoft Office OneNote/16.6/171005 (iOS/11.1.1; Phone; en-US; AppStore; Apple/iPhone10,1)"
[25/Nov/2017:20:02:01 +0100] "POST /OneNote/Testbook/_vti_bin/webs.asmx HTTP/1.1" 401 754 "-" "OneNote/16006000.17100500 CFNetwork/889.9 Darwin/17.2.0"
[25/Nov/2017:20:02:01 +0100] "HEAD /OneNote/Testbook/ HTTP/1.1" 302 137 "-" "Microsoft Office OneNote/16.6/171005 (iOS/11.1.1; Phone; en-US; AppStore; Apple/iPhone10,1)"
[25/Nov/2017:20:02:01 +0100] "POST /OneNote/Testbook/_vti_bin/webs.asmx HTTP/1.1" 401 754 "-" "OneNote/16.6/171005 (iOS/11.1.1; Phone; en-US; AppStore; Apple/iPhone10,1)"
[25/Nov/2017:20:02:01 +0100] "POST /OneNote/Testbook/_vti_bin/webs.asmx HTTP/1.1" 200 1462 "-" "OneNote/16.6/171005 (iOS/11.1.1; Phone; en-US; AppStore; Apple/iPhone10,1)"
[25/Nov/2017:20:02:02 +0100] "POST /OneNote/Testbook/_vti_bin/webs.asmx HTTP/1.1" 401 714 "-" "OneNote/16.6/171005 (iOS/11.1.1; Phone; en-US; AppStore; Apple/iPhone10,1)"
[25/Nov/2017:20:02:02 +0100] "HEAD /OneNote/Testbook/ HTTP/1.1" 302 137 "-" "Microsoft Office OneNote/16.6/171005 (iOS/11.1.1; Phone; en-US; AppStore; Apple/iPhone10,1)"
[25/Nov/2017:20:02:02 +0100] "POST /OneNote/Testbook/_vti_bin/webs.asmx HTTP/1.1" 200 1346 "-" "OneNote/16.6/171005 (iOS/11.1.1; Phone; en-US; AppStore; Apple/iPhone10,1)"
[25/Nov/2017:20:02:02 +0100] "POST /_vti_bin/lists.asmx HTTP/1.1" 500 1230 "-" "OneNote/16006000.17100500 CFNetwork/889.9 Darwin/17.2.0"
[25/Nov/2017:20:02:02 +0100] "HEAD /OneNote/Testbook/ HTTP/1.1" 401 137 "-" "Microsoft Office OneNote/16.6/171005 (iOS/11.1.1; Phone; en-US; AppStore; Apple/iPhone10,1)"
[25/Nov/2017:20:02:02 +0100] "HEAD /_vti_bin/OneNote.ashx HTTP/1.1" 404 137 "-" "Microsoft Office OneNote/16.6/171005 (iOS/11.1.1; Phone; en-US; AppStore; Apple/iPhone10,1)"
[25/Nov/2017:20:02:02 +0100] "HEAD /OneNote/Testbook/ HTTP/1.1" 401 572 "-" "Microsoft Office OneNote/16.6/171005 (iOS/11.1.1; Phone; en-US; AppStore; Apple/iPhone10,1)"
[25/Nov/2017:20:02:03 +0100] "HEAD /OneNote/Testbook/ HTTP/1.1" 302 695 "-" "Microsoft Office OneNote/16.6/171005 (iOS/11.1.1; Phone; en-US; AppStore; Apple/iPhone10,1)"
[25/Nov/2017:20:02:03 +0100] "HEAD /OneNote/Testbook/ HTTP/1.1" 401 137 "-" "Microsoft Office OneNote/16.6/171005 (iOS/11.1.1; Phone; en-US; AppStore; Apple/iPhone10,1)"
[25/Nov/2017:20:02:03 +0100] "HEAD /OneNote/Testbook/ HTTP/1.1" 302 696 "-" "Microsoft Office OneNote/16.6/171005 (iOS/11.1.1; Phone; en-US; AppStore; Apple/iPhone10,1)"
[25/Nov/2017:20:02:05 +0100] "HEAD /OneNote/Testbook/ HTTP/1.1" 302 137 "-" "Microsoft Office OneNote/16.6/171005 (iOS/11.1.1; Phone; en-US; AppStore; Apple/iPhone10,1)"
[25/Nov/2017:20:02:06 +0100] "HEAD /OneNote/Testbook/ HTTP/1.1" 302 137 "-" "Microsoft Office OneNote/16.6/171005 (iOS/11.1.1; Phone; en-US; AppStore; Apple/iPhone10,1)"
[25/Nov/2017:20:02:06 +0100] "HEAD /OneNote/Testbook/ HTTP/1.1" 401 137 "-" "Microsoft Office OneNote/16.6/171005 (iOS/11.1.1; Phone; en-US; AppStore; Apple/iPhone10,1)"
[25/Nov/2017:20:02:07 +0100] "HEAD /OneNote/Testbook/ HTTP/1.1" 401 572 "-" "Microsoft Office OneNote/16.6/171005 (iOS/11.1.1; Phone; en-US; AppStore; Apple/iPhone10,1)"
[25/Nov/2017:20:02:07 +0100] "HEAD /OneNote/Testbook/ HTTP/1.1" 302 695 "-" "Microsoft Office OneNote/16.6/171005 (iOS/11.1.1; Phone; en-US; AppStore; Apple/iPhone10,1)"
[25/Nov/2017:20:02:07 +0100] "HEAD /OneNote/Testbook/ HTTP/1.1" 401 137 "-" "Microsoft Office OneNote/16.6/171005 (iOS/11.1.1; Phone; en-US; AppStore; Apple/iPhone10,1)"
[25/Nov/2017:20:02:07 +0100] "HEAD /OneNote/Testbook/ HTTP/1.1" 302 696 "-" "Microsoft Office OneNote/16.6/171005 (iOS/11.1.1; Phone; en-US; AppStore; Apple/iPhone10,1)"
[25/Nov/2017:20:02:08 +0100] "HEAD /OneNote/Testbook/ HTTP/1.1" 401 137 "-" "Microsoft Office OneNote/16.6/171005 (iOS/11.1.1; Phone; en-US; AppStore; Apple/iPhone10,1)"
[25/Nov/2017:20:02:08 +0100] "HEAD /OneNote/Testbook/ HTTP/1.1" 302 696 "-" "Microsoft Office OneNote/16.6/171005 (iOS/11.1.1; Phone; en-US; AppStore; Apple/iPhone10,1)"
[25/Nov/2017:20:02:10 +0100] "POST /_vti_bin/lists.asmx HTTP/1.1" 500 1230 "-" "OneNote/16006000.17100500 CFNetwork/889.9 Darwin/17.2.0"
[25/Nov/2017:20:02:11 +0100] "HEAD /OneNote/Testbook/ HTTP/1.1" 302 137 "-" "Microsoft Office OneNote/16.6/171005 (iOS/11.1.1; Phone; en-US; AppStore; Apple/iPhone10,1)"
[25/Nov/2017:20:02:11 +0100] "HEAD /OneNote/Testbook/ HTTP/1.1" 302 137 "-" "Microsoft Office OneNote/16.6/171005 (iOS/11.1.1; Phone; en-US; AppStore; Apple/iPhone10,1)"
[25/Nov/2017:20:02:12 +0100] "HEAD /OneNote/Testbook/ HTTP/1.1" 302 137 "-" "Microsoft Office OneNote/16.6/171005 (iOS/11.1.1; Phone; en-US; AppStore; Apple/iPhone10,1)"
[25/Nov/2017:20:02:12 +0100] "HEAD /OneNote/Testbook/ HTTP/1.1" 302 137 "-" "Microsoft Office OneNote/16.6/171005 (iOS/11.1.1; Phone; en-US; AppStore; Apple/iPhone10,1)"
[25/Nov/2017:20:02:13 +0100] "HEAD /OneNote/Testbook/ HTTP/1.1" 302 137 "-" "Microsoft Office OneNote/16.6/171005 (iOS/11.1.1; Phone; en-US; AppStore; Apple/iPhone10,1)"
```

The log files I found in `c:\Program files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS\` do not show any useful errors or information (to me at least).

Answer (score 1):

The SharePoint App does not support SharePoint Foundation. You must be running SharePoint Server 2013 Standard, Enterprise, SharePoint 2016, or SharePoint Online.

[SharePoint mobile app for iOS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SharePoint-mobile-app-for-iOS-339402ce-16bb-4c97-9475-0c5375ccef7a)

Comment: Where in the link do you read that it's specifically not for 2013 Foundation? (Currently trying to install SP2016 and SQL server to see if the issues are gone - have a license for that too. Wanted to avoid this since it's even more bloaty than 2013)

Comment: The link I provided has the editions and versions supported. The App needs the UPSA to operate which Foundation doesn’t have.

Comment: Ok, finally I got SP2016 installed. Unfortunately exactly the same; for the SharePoint app as well as for OneNote. Could there be any setting/app/service on SP side for iOS? Hard to believe that I am the one person trying to connect an iOS device ...

Comment: Did you create the UPSA and MySite host? If I recall correctly, the Office Apps on iOS require an Office 365 Sub to use.

Comment: Yes, UPSA is enabled (you mean like https://snag.gy/CjPoOs.jpg ?) I did not create "MySite host" - and it does not seem trivial. Do you have a reference about the mentioned Sharepoint requirements? (I only know this https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SharePoint-mobile-app-for-iOS-339402ce-16bb-4c97-9475-0c5375ccef7a and all it says it requires 2013, 2016, NTLM but not Kerberos/Basic auth)

Comment: I don't think the requirements are outlined but given it requires the social/follow functionality, we can determine it requires a UPSA, the user to have a profile in the UPSA, and a MySite Host along with a user having a MySite (required for Follow functionality).